# Using user defined Java Class in Clojure with Gradle

Tags: java, clojure, gradle, interop

I'm currently using Gradle to build a project. I have a Java class I've defined that provides some utility functions and I'd like to reuse these in the Clojure portion of the project. This is easy between multiple Java files because I can just include them in the same package and be done with it.

So for example, if I have a package com.example.mypackage which contains the class MyClass which contains a static method myMethod, how can I use this method in my Clojure code?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
(println (MyClass/myMethod "parameter"))
```

I think this is the correct in code implementation for what I want to do, but I have no idea how to to actually access MyClass. I've tried many variations of import and require like this:

```
(import '(com.example.mypackage MyClass))
```

Unfortunately, I've had no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'd have to provide more details, such as how you build the Clojure and Java code with Gradle. At the end of the day, someone has to make sure that the Java code is on the Clojure program's class path.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is your project's structure and how are you running your application? When you are at the REPL and you evaluate `(import '(com.example.mypackage MyClass))` what is the result? If it is an exception, then your class is not in the classpath.

Comment: That was it, it wasn't in the classpath. Thanks!